# Python read very small decimal number

Tags: python

My program reads a file with numbers and stores it in an array.

One value, say X is 0.0000001

```
dataset2d = [[float(digit) for digit in line.strip().split()] for line in file]
Y= dataset2d[0][2] #(fixed position in file)
C = 0.5 * math.log((A+ Y)/(B+ Y))  #This gives divide by zero error. B can be 0 though.
```

I'm storing the values in a float array.
When I print the array, the X values is being displayed on console as 1e-07
Now when I store it to a variable say Y, and divide a number with Y I get divide by zero error.

I want use this number is divisor, and hence to avoid divide by zero error, I want the actual value and not approximated value.

How do I do this in Python? That is, read and store the very small X value correctly in my array.

Note : If I use decimal, can I do this for the entire array? Or just for this one value which is at the same place?

Comment: "Now when I read it, it reads as 0.0"  -- I'm not sure I understand that bit of your question.  Could you clarify?  Even posting some example code that we can use to reproduce the problem would go a long way :)

Comment: Could you post some code as to how you are doing the casting?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: Do you have this in your code: `from decimal import *`? You need to be using the decimal module. Are you?

Comment: There's no way Python is going to "lose" the value, if it's 1e-07 in one context it won't suddenly change to 0.0 in another. Using `Decimal` won't help, your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @TJonS: No..I added it, but I don't know how to use it. I tried decimal() instead of float above with the import. But that didn't work

Comment: @user2441441, did you see the link I posted? That is the Official Documentation on it. Better than anything I would say! :)

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I have clarified that part. Any suggestions?

Comment: Still not clear enough. Show the line that assigns `Y` and the line that gives the divide-by-zero error.

Comment: @MarkRansom Added those lines...

Comment: OK, very good. Now what happens when you `print repr(dataset2d[0][2])`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: repr(dataset2d[0][2]): 0.0 is printed.

Comment: In that case why do you say the value is 1e-07? Obviously it is not.

Comment: @MarkRansom because when I  print the dataset2d, it prints it as 1e-07 in that place on the console.{dataset2d[0][2]}

Comment: I think perhaps you have your dimensions mixed up and you're looking at `dataset2d[2][0]` instead. Or maybe counting incorrectly.

Comment: @MarkRansom You are correct! Feeling stupid now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm so glad I could help. Don't feel stupid, it's all part of the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using the Python decimal module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html YOu can use it for your whole array. As to how to use it, see the link. :)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I  already have a ton of calculations with the float values. When I changed it all to Decimal, I'm getting errors...I'm looking into it..

Answer (score -1):

As you mention in your note, I would suggest using the decimal module. In that case, definitely use it for all of the values. Just to demonstrate why:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> x = D(".01")
>>> 0.3/x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'
```

Comment: Also notice how I read the number into decimal as the original string. If you don't, it will read that number as a normal float *and then* store the approximate [IEEE floating point value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) as a decimal.